# How do I build a dc generator at home for my presentaion?

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors, generator

I'm having a presentation about dc generators and I wanted to demonstrate how it works. Anyone have an idea on how to build one. I left my electric motors at home because of Christmas break, now I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a presentation it might makes sense to reproduce one of [Faraday's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday's_law_of_induction) original experiments which give more of a visible insight into what is going on than a modern generator which is essentially just a sealed box.

Something like the experiment in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwIdZjjd8fo) would be quick and easy to set up.

Obviously making a rotating armature which produces a steady current is a bit more difficult than just moving a magnet in and out of a coil but in some ways the simple version demonstrates the underlying concept better.

Comment: will this light an led if I keep spinning the magnet ? :D

Comment: It is certainly possible, it helps that very powerful magnets are now fairy chap and easily available https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZpa7FYR_pw

Comment: ok, thanks. this really helped me a lot mate. :D :D

Comment: Chris, can I use this magnets ? 
http://www.lazada.com.ph/autoleader-200-neodymium-disc-magnets-3-x-15mm-strong-rare-earthmagnet-n35-warhammer-40k-4266759.html

Comment: yes something like that shoudl be ideal